# v-for loop generating list items that will get rearranged based on an associated value (ranking system)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

A counter gets incremented by a custom value.
Each increment value gets stored with its refcount that tracks how many times it occurred.
An ordered list shows all increment values entered so far by number of occurrences.
Higher rank means more occurrence.

[image: animation of the "feature"]

#### Before venturing futher, a disclaimer:

- I can't make prettier work on my VS Code, so I resort to formatting (often poorly) the code myself. `#No longer the case`
- The reason behind the variable names is that I need long (to the point of excess) names so I can reason about my code and I find udnerscores soothing for some reason.

That being said: I will welcome every remark, reproach, fist shaking with the same amount (a lot) of gratitude that I will welcome criticism (of any kind) and advice.

### The code:

Two components: Parent: `CounterInDis.vue` and child: `CounterDisplay.vue`.

`CounterInDis.vue`:

```js
<script>
import CounterDisplay from './CounterDisplay.vue';
let count = 0;
let increment = 0;
let last_value = 0;
let values_occurrence = {};
let sorted_values = [];
export default {
    components: { CounterDisplay },
    data() {
        return {
            count: count,
            last_value: last_value,
            increment: increment,
            values_occurrence: values_occurrence,
            sorted_values: sorted_values,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        increment_count() {
            let checked = this.is_increment_a_number(this.increment)
            if (checked == 0) { return }
            this.last_value = checked;
            this.count += checked;
            this.update_values_occurrence(checked);
            this.sort_by_occurrence();
        },

        is_increment_a_number(amount) {
            if (typeof amount != 'number') { amount = 0; };
            return amount;
        },

        update_values_occurrence(amount) {
            if (!values_occurrence[amount]) {
                values_occurrence[amount] = 0;
            }
            values_occurrence[amount] += 1
        },

        sort_by_occurrence() {
            const keys_n_values = Object.entries(this.values_occurrence);
            keys_n_values.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
            sorted_values = keys_n_values.map((entry) => entry[0]);
        },

    },

    computed: {
        to_the_doms_with_you() {
            return {
                current_count: this.count,
                last_value: this.last_value,
                current_increment: this.increment,
                values_occurrence: this.values_occurrence,
                sorted_values: sorted_values, //this.sorted_values won't make the list display, idk why
            }
        },
    },
}
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Counter</h3>
        <h4>Welcome to the new and improved counter!</h4>
        <CounterDisplay :counter_display_values="to_the_doms_with_you" />

        <button v-on:click="increment_count">Increment dat count</button>

        <div>
            <label for="increment">Increment by</label>
            <input type="number" v-model="increment">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

`CounterDisplay.vue`.

```js
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        counter_display_values: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    }
}
</script>
<template>
    <p>The Counter is at {{ counter_display_values.current_count }}.</p>
    <p v-if="counter_display_values.last_value == 0">Click the button and start counting.</p>
    <p v-else>Last increment's value: {{ counter_display_values.last_value }}</p>

    <div class="fixed_width">
        <p class="half">To each value, its number of occurrences:
        <pre>{{ counter_display_values.values_occurrence }}</pre>
        </p>

        <p>Ranked occurrences:</p>
        <ol class="half">
            <li v-for="value in counter_display_values.sorted_values" v-bind:key="value">
                {{ value }}
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</template>
<style>
.full {
    height: 250px;
}

.half {
    height: 110px;
}
</style>
```

### The implementation:

Two components: Parent: `CounterInDis.vue` and child: `CounterDisplay.vue`.

`CounterInDis.vue` has a "number" input field bound to the variable `increment`. And a button that fires the function `increment_count`.
`increment_count` passes `increment` to the function `is_increment_a_number` that loosely checks if `increment` is a number, and either returns `0` if `typeof increment != 'number'` or returns `increment`.
if `is_increment_a_number` returned a `0`, `increment_amount` exits.
otherwise:
it updates the variable `last_value` with `increment` (regardless if it's `increment === last_value` or not).
then, it adds `increment` to the variable `count` (the count).
then, it passes `increment` to the function `update_values_occurrence`.
`update_value_occurrence` creates a new entry in the `values_occurrence` dict if `increment` isn't already there with the refcount of `0`, then it increments the refcount by 1.
then, it (`increment_count`) fires the function `sort_by_occurrence`.
`sort_by_occurrence` get `values_occurrence`'s entries, sort them (which refcount is greater) then `map` the sorted keys to the array `sorted_values`.
by now, `computed` detected changes in the variables it's watching (basically, all of them) and pass them down as props the child component.
**something i don't understand**: inside the object returned by `computed`:
`sorted_values: this.sorted_values` won't display the array in the child component.
`sorted_values: sorted_values` shows the array inside the child component. why?

inside `CounterDisplay.vue`: the properties of the object get displayed.

- a `v-for` that iterates over* the `sorted_values` array and uses each value as its own `key` -> My reasoning is that this ensures the keys will remain unique since no value can have a duplicate.

Is my reasoning correct? Is there a better way to generate the list items and move them around based on their rank?
Thank you (:

Comment: Doing indentation manually is fine, but please do it properly. Your earlier indentation and whitespace was inconsistent and made the code a bit harder to read. There are plenty of JavaScript linting/formatting tools out there. If you're using `npm`, there's also some npm tools that can help you with this. If you're not using `npm`, well... then you just have some more to learn :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need these:

```
let count = 0;
let increment = 0;
let last_value = 0;
let values_occurrence = {};
let sorted_values = [];
```

Instead you should assign those values within the `data()` of your component.
This is actually the reason why `this.sorted_values` doesn't work, because this line:

`sorted_values = keys_n_values.map((entry) => entry[0]);`

is **reassigning** the *outer* `sorted_values` but not `this.sorted_values`. As the outer sorted_values changes reference completely, the outer `sorted_values` is now separated from `this.sorted_values`. If you would have had more than one component of `CounterInDis` this would have caused a bug that both of them are using the same `sorted_values` data. Always put your component-specific values inside the component and don't use data from outside!

---

`sorted_values` could actually be a computed property, and as such there's no need for the `sort_by_occourence` at all -- all that code can actually just be the computed property:

```
computed: {
    ...
    sorted_values() {
        let keys_n_values = Object.entries(this.values_occurrence);
        keys_n_values.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
        return keys_n_values.map((entry) => entry[0]);
    }
}
```

(I wouldn't use `const keys_n_values` because you are mutating the array with sort)

---

`this.counter` can also be a computed property because it is just the sum of all values keys in the array multiplied by their value.

---

> a v-for that iterates of the sorted_values array and uses each value as its own key -> My reasoning is that this ensures the keys will remain unique since no value can have a duplicate.

That reasoning is correct, yes. Just a tip: `v-bind:key` is the same as `:key`. Prefer to be consistent, in some cases - e.g. `:counter_display_values` you are just using the colon.

Comment: but of course! `this.sorted_values` is shorthand for `this.$data.sorted_values` if the outside `sorted_values` change its reference to a different array, then the one inside `data` will never get updated with how the code i wrote works. also: keep data inside `data()`, pretty self evident in hindsight. i managed to make prettier work in vscode so i will update the code's formatting (without changing the code as per CR's rules) and will keep in mind all of your recommendations. thank you for your time and effort ( : top notch answer.

Comment: @dhiaagr You're welcome. Just FYI: Even formatting edits in your question can invalidate answers, but this time I changed that formatting part to become a comment instead. Try to fix formatting before you post questions on Code Review as it's a very easy thing to post an answer just highlighting the formatting aspects (and it's fine to do that according to this site standards - which I agree with). And great first question btw, hope to see similar interesting questions from you in the future! I don't often review code here these days, but I couldn't resist this one :)

Comment: Thank you so much, that means a lot ( : I will keep all your valid points in mind. Hope to get more of your answers soon, too ( :